# How to bring a certain cell to front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view, I have three sections, of which the first section contains a image cell, the second section contains segment control cell, and the third section contains some label cells.
What I am doing is when the user scrolls up the table view, everything will scroll up but the position of the segment control cell will be fixed at the upper margin of the screen.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfCurrentHeaderCell =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]          ;
UITableViewCell *headerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfCurrentHeaderCell];
if (headerCell.frame.origin.y < self.tableView.contentOffset.y)
{
    self.cellHead.hidden = NO;
    self.cellHead.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, self.cellHead.frame.size.width, self.cellHead.frame.size.height);        
}
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.cellHead];
}
```

But the function bringSubviewToFront: does not seem to work here (the second section will be covered by the third section). I think it is because the cells are not the subviews of the table view.
What can I do if I want to pull the segment control cell to the front?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the segment control as a header instead of a cell in the tableview, using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

then, you would have 2 sections,

```
1. image cell
2. segment control as header, labels as the cells
```

Comment: Hi, Lewen, thank you for your reply. but it does not work as well. The head view will go up out of the view when scrolling.